# Hibernate Error Invalid Column Name

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am trying to make a one to many and many to one relation in hibernate and spring.

below is my code for product class

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Product")
public class Product implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="productId")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer productId;

    @Column(name="productName")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name="productPrice")
    private int productPrice;


    //---------------------------------------item mapped to category------------------------------------------//
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name="CategoryProduct",
            joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="productId")
    )
    private Category category;
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//



    public Integer getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(Integer productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public int getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(int productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }




}
```

below is my code for category class

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import java.io.Serializable;
@Entity
@Table(name="Category")
public class Category implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="categoryId")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer categoryId;

    @Column(name="categoryName")
    private String categoryName;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name="CategoryProduct",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="categoryId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="productId")
    )
    public Set<Product> product;


    public Integer getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(Integer categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public Set<Product> getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Set<Product> product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

}
```

---

Whenever i run the code i am getting Invalid column name 'category_categoryId'.

Structure of my tables
Product has column as productId, poductName and productPrice
category has columns as categoryId, categoryName
categoryproducts has columns as categoryId and productId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to put `inverseJoinColumns` at your @JoinTable in Product Class. This cause hibernate to use their convention of joinTable which is `<ClassName>_<columnName>`. Change it to

```
@JoinTable(
    name="CategoryProduct",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="productId"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="categoryId")
)
private Category category;
```

However, seeing at your design, you are actually creating 2 uni-directional association between product and category. If you want to create bi-directional association, I suggest you change the One side (Category), to use mappedBy

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="category", cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
public Set<Product> product;
```

It will generally achieve the same result. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, the solution worked for me. As I am a pretty new at Hibernate i will review the design and consider your idea.